# Ignite Grid can't get started with open jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ignite

Usually I do not provide a configuration for ignite. I just do:

```
this.ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(new IgniteConfiguration());
```

and perform some operations on the ignite:

```
this.ignite.getOrCreateCache(Identifiers.BRAND_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE).removeAll();
this.ignite.getOrCreateCache(Identifiers.BRAND_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE).putAll(map);
```

It works fine. For testing purposes I now wanted to create an in memory database using ignite to have a database from which I can load items into my ignite cache. So I created a jdbc connection:

```
public class DefaultConnection {

    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection(String driverName, String host, String user, String password) throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null) {
            return connection;
        } else {
            try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                log.severe(e.getMessage());

                return null;
            }

            if (user == null || password == null) {
                return DriverManager.getConnection(host);
            }

            return DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
        }
    }
}

this.DRIVER_NAME = "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver";
this.HOST = "jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/";
this.connection = DefaultConnection.getConnection(DRIVER_NAME, HOST, null, null);

... // create tables and insert some data
```

**ATTENTION** I yet did not load the data from the database into the cache using the `.loadCache(null)` function on `ignite.getOrCreateCache("MyCache")`. I just created some tables with some data in it.

When I now want to perform operations on my empty cache like a simple get:

```
 this.ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(new IgniteConfiguration());
 this.ignite.getOrCreateCache("MyCache").get("123456");
```

I get the following error:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [igniteInstanceName=null, state=STOPPED]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [igniteInstanceName=null, state=STOPPED]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.illegalState(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.readLock(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.guard(IgniteKernal.java:3709)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.getOrCreateCache(IgniteKernal.java:3142)
    at de.test.MyService.publishItemsFromCacheQuery(ProviderService.java:335)
    at de.test.MyService.lambda$null$12(ProviderService.java:286)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6633)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:6800)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6626)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6590)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6533)
    at de.test.MyService.lambda$null$14(ProviderService.java:286)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onNext(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onSubscribe(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3114)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3000)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2967)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2914)
    at de.test.MyService.lambda$getAverageBenchmarkItems$15(ProviderService.java:276)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect.subscribe(MonoCollect.java:66)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1161)
    at de.test.MyServiceTest.getAverageBenchmarkItemsNegative(ProviderServiceTest.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I do not create a jdbc connection to ignite everything works fine again.

Example Cache configuration of "MyCache":

```
private CacheConfiguration<String, MyItem> getCacheConfiguration() {
    final CacheConfiguration<String, MyItem> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>("MyCache");

    cacheConfiguration.setName("MyCache");
    cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, MyItem.class);
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(MyItemCacheStore.class.getName()));
    cacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(false);
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cacheConfiguration.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setEvictionPolicy(new LruEvictionPolicy());

    return cacheConfiguration;
}
```

Why isnt ignite able to build the grid when there is an open jdbc connection to ignite?

**EDIT**

Some additional informations: I only need the jdbc connection for my unit tests. This exception is only appearing using `gradlew test` If I run the unit tests the "normal" way everything works fine

**EDIT 2**

[Example project](https://TMarc@bitbucket.org/TMarc/item-service.git)

Note: Exception only appears when running `gradlew test` and when the service test class is annotated with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. In no other cases

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your code, you surely can use jdbc and native api at the same time with no problems. The exception says that grid is stopped, please check that it hasn't been stopped in some other place. If it still doesn't work for you, could you please share a reproduce on github, so I can review your code or/and reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: I added the git example project. Note: Exception only appears when running `gradlew test` and when the service test class is annotated with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. In no other cases

Comment: I tried your app and it works fine for me.

Comment: `gradlew test` works fine for you?

Comment: ."""/gradlew test
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :compileJava
Note: /home/mcherkas/ws/support/item-service/src/main/java/de/test/provider/ProviderService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
"""
I've never used gradle before, may be I did something wrong?

Comment: If you ran `gradlew test` you did it right... even though.. it is very strange that you dont get the exception. Until now I let 7 different colleagues checkout the example repository and ran `gradlew test` and they all got the exception.